# Solving for the volume of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, volume

Can anyone explain why I was incorrect in this problem: [image]

I used a tetrahedron solver online, http://rechneronline.de/pi/tetrahedron.php, and it says I have the right answer.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ are very different things...

Comment: yes and online if I look up the equation it shows a $\sqrt 2$

Comment: Don't trust everything you read online...

Comment: Ok so does the real equation have a $\sqrt 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $S$ denotes the length of a side, your answer is correct.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Formulas_for_a_regular_tetrahedron).

Comment: Ok thanks. Just trying to prepare for this next test

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $S$ (or is it $S'$?) indicates side length and not surface area, you're correct.